# $e^{At} e^{Bt} = e^{(A+B)t} e^{\big(\frac{t^2}{2}[A,B]\big)}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{R}).$ Suppose that $[A,[A,B]]=[B,[A,B]]=0$.

Then $e^{At} e^{Bt} = e^{(A+B)t} e^{\big(\frac{t^2}{2}[A,B]\big)}$.

**My attempt**

Let $f(t) = e^{-(A+B)t}e^{At} e^{Bt}$ and $g(t) = e^{\big(\frac{t^2}{2}[A,B]\big)} $. Then $f(0) = I_n$ and $g(0)=I_n$.

I'm trying to show that $g$ and $f$ are solutions of a same differential equation.

We have:

$$f'(t) = -(A+B)e^{-(A+B)t}e^{At} e^{Bt} + e^{-(A+B)t}(Ae^{At} e^{Bt} +e^{At} Be^{Bt})$$
$$=-(A+B)e^{-(A+B)t}e^{At} e^{Bt} + e^{-(A+B)t}Ae^{At} e^{Bt} +e^{-(A+B)t}e^{At} Be^{Bt}$$

$$=-Ae^{-(A+B)t}e^{At}e^{Bt}  - Be^{-(A+B)t}e^{At}e^{Bt} + e^{-(A+B)t}Ae^{At} e^{Bt} +e^{-(A+B)t}e^{At} Be^{Bt}$$

$$g'(t) = t[A,B]e^{\big(\frac{t^2}{2}[A,B]\big)}$$

I'm stuck here. How can I prove that $g'(t) = f'(t)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have shown that
$$
f' = -(A+B)f + e^{-(A+B)t}e^{At}(A+B)e^{Bt}
$$
first thing you want to do is transform the second term into the form: "Something$\times f$". Well's let's do just that:
Claim one:
$$
[A^n, B] = n[A,B]A^{n-1}
$$
Proof: Induction. $n=1$ is trivial. Suppose we know this for $n$, then
$$
[A^{n+1}, B] = A[A^n, B] + [A, B]A^{n} = (n+1)[A,B]A^{n}
$$
(I'm using $[A,[A,B]]=0$ heavily). Hence
$$
[e^{At},B] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{t^n}{n!}[A^n, B] = t[A,B] e^{tA}\Longrightarrow e^{tA}B=Be^{tA} + t[A,B]e^{tA}
$$
which means
$$
f' = -(A+B)f + e^{-(A+B)t}(A+B)e^{tA}e^{tB}+t[A,B]f = t[A,B]f
$$
So you have a differential equation $\dot{x}-t[A,B]x=0$ and two solutions.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't see where you used $[A,[A,B]]=0$.

Comment: I have commuted $A$ and $[A,B]$ in a few places. Once is in the induction proof. The second time is in the final form of $f'$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use the Baker Campbell Hausdorff formula

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#An_explicit_Baker.E2.80.93Campbell.E2.80.93Hausdorff_formula

In this case $log(exp(tA)exp(tB))= tA+tB+{t^2\over 2}[A,B]$, we have $exp( tA+tB+{t^2\over 2}[A,B])=exp(t(A+B))exp({t^2\over 2}[A,B])$ since $[A+B,[A,B]]=0$.

Comment: As far as I know this is how you prove Baker-Campbell-Hausdroff formula in the first place. At least I can't think of any proof of this formula which is easier than proving the question of the OP.

Comment: Usually exercises are solved by applying theorems which are of course more difficult than the exercise. Anyway I am still wondering how the BCH formula can be deduced from this particular case

Comment: This is special case of BCH for $t=1$ and $[A,[A,B]]=[B,[A,B]]=0$. More general cases can be proved using similar method of the OP, proving two things satisfy the same ODE, then putting $t=1$. But, again, I might be just ignorant and there is even a simpler proof which I don't know of.